# How can you copy the entire file system of a prior build phase in a Dockerfile without using FROM to do it?

Tags: docker, artifactory

We use JFrog Artifactory for managing Docker images created from Dockerfiles. It has a nice feature where you can see all the "layers" that were involved in creating any given final Docker image.

We have to be careful though, so that credentials do not wind up showing in the layers where they were used. The way we currently do this is by using multistage builds with "COPY --from".

However recently we needed to use credentials for a particular yum repository, which is supplying many dependencies that we need (thousands of files spread throughout the file system). I used yum-config-manager to set the password and username from ENV variables. However even if I use `FROM depbuilder`, the commands from all the prior stages (including `depbuilder`) now become visible in Artifactory.

I need to avoid that from happening, and a colleage suggested that we could simply do this:

`COPY --from=depbuilder / /`

And that way it wouldn't show the other stage's steps as part of the history of the build in Artifactory. However I'm afraid that this command might not set all the ownership and permissions correctly, or it might miss certain files, since the documentation on how it works seems spotty at best.

So what's the best way to copy everything from a prior build stage in a way that would be invisible to someone looking at the build layers in Artifactory?

Here is a screenshot showing what the layers look like in Artifactory: (if we expand the RUN steps, currently we could see the credentials passed into docker via ENV since they become part of the URL for Artifactory)

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure it *doesn't* copy the attributes properly? I'd test this to be sure. In my experience it does copy quite faithfully and `--from` is the answer.

Comment: After I did a copy with `COPY --from=depbuilder / /` then the Swift compiler seemed to start having linker errors. I'm worried that copying things this way might be losing some permissions info.

Comment: You might want to refocus this question on the linker errors, not on your hypothesis that it's the copy problem.